# Windows 10 Automatic Repair FAIL (constant loop)

Tags: windows, system-restore

I upgraded my pc to Windows 10 few weeks ago and it was all good until today when without warning the pc decides to constantly display the blue screen with the error code `IO1_INITIALIZATION_FAILED`. I can't seem to find the fix of this anywhere on the internet. The repair option from "Advanced options" doesn't work neither is downgrading or trying to access a restore point which i have created in the past.  How do I fix this problem without formatting my PC. Is there a command line code to do this or any other smart option?

[image: http://oi57.tinypic.com/20krk1k.jpg]

[image: http://oi57.tinypic.com/16c12ro.jpg]

Comment: you get this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559133%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. Microsoft doesn't give any tips to solve it. Post more details about your device (hardware, installed software)